# URL Video Stream of IP Camera

Tags: opencv, url, video-streaming, ip-camera

I have a **Teledyne Dalsa Genie Nano XL** camera : connecting it to the PC it gets assigned the following **IP Address**: 192.168.0.20

How do I find or setup the **URL Video Stream** for the camera in order to access its video stream through standard opencv instruction `cap=cv2.VideoCapture('url')`?

Any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: That's a GigE Vision industrial camera, isn't it? Generally the standard builds of OpenCV don't include support for any of the VideoIO backends that could support those cameras, you need to build your own with the appropriate SDK. Things have improved over time, but those backends still provide only a limited functionality -- fine for quick prototyping, but I've found it better to use the SDK (in my case PVAPI) directly for acquisition.

Comment: Re-building OpenCV with the additional [VideoIO backends](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/d0/da7/videoio_overview.html) will take some work and probably digging through the OpenCV sources with an uncertain outcome. Personally, I'd take the Dalsa SDK (I guess Sapera?) and look through the C++ samples to find one that shows basic grabbing of frames and write a simple class for acquiring images from the camera. You seem to want Python, so I'd wrap using Boost.Python, representing the images as numpy arrays just like OpenCV does.

Comment: Thank you  A LOT @DanMašek. Your help is truly appreciated, if it is fine with you I will update you with the progress I make in that direction and maybe share code and wrappers that will be useful for others for the same application

Comment: No problem, let me know. :)

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are trying to stream from an IP camera via rtsp. So, you can achieve it by this line of code:

**Python version**:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('rtsp://admin:admin@192.168.0.20:554/stream1 latency=0')
```

**C++ version**:

```
cv::VideoCapture cap("rtsp://admin:admin@192.168.0.20:554/stream1 latency=0");
```

Here, the first `admin` indicates the `username` used to connect to your ip camera, and the second corresponds to `password`. By default, rtsp connection uses 554 port, but you may refer to your camera document to double-check it.

The string `:554/stream1` varies depending on your camera brand. So you should check your manual for rtsp connection string.

The parameter `latency=0` means you want to stream from camera without any delay. By default, rtsp connection creates a latency for buffer (something like 2-5 seconds), and this leads to some delay from actual content.

Comment: That is not the case: apparently this device does not support rtsp protocol

Comment: how can you be so sure? can you connect to your camera via any internet browser?

Comment: apparently not: the camera has an IP but I am not able to access it in any way from a internet browser. Any experience with that?

Comment: If you just simply entered your camera ip into your browser, that does not make any sense. you should connect via browser using a connection string defined by your manufacturer. ask your camera provider about it.

Comment: Do you have experince with Sapera  ++ ? That is what is needed to actually grab frames from the camera

Comment: No, but seems like it's a kind of your camera's SDK. I don't think it's the only choice for simply capturing from your camera.